# Perguntas migradas trazem sua votação original junto?

Tags: suporte, migração

A seguinte pergunta foi migrada do SO para cá hoje:

[Como ordenar uma ListBox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40250/ordenar-uma-lixtbox-em-c)

É uma pergunta que acredito se encaixar bem em nossa comunidade. Um desenvolvedor está com dificuldades para usar um componente de uma plataforma de software e pede ajuda.

Porém a pergunta tinha um voto negativo quando a encontrei. Acho que o voto negativo foi dado ainda no SO em inglês, visto que até os comentários em inglês foram migrados. Eu gostaria apenas de confirmar ou desfazer essa suspeita.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O voto conta é daqui mesmo. Perguntas migradas vêm com pontuação zerada, independentemente dos votos no site de origem.

[Neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895416/ordenar-uma-lixtbox-em-c-sharp?noredirect=1) é possível acessar a pergunta no SO, e comprovar que lá ela tinha pontuação de -4.  No nosso site, ela está com pontuação zero (+1/-1, como pode ser comprovado clicando no placar*)

---

<sup>*** [Requer certa pontuação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)**</sup>